Failed to parse package - Kotlin install apk
I'm trying to install an apk via kotlin. My app downloads the apk from github however when trying to install the apk, it says "failed to parse package"
In my androidmanifest.xml I have
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<provider
      android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">

      <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>

and my provider paths xml is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>

and my kotlin function is
val apkFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context,
    context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
    File(apkFilePath)
)
val install = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
install.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
install.setDataAndType(apkFileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
context.startActivity(install)

I have checked the md5sum of both the file hosted on GitHub, and the file downloaded by my app, and they both match, and the file downloaded by GitHub is installable by Chrom and the default file manager. I assume then, it's a permissions issue, but I don't know what permissions I am missing.
Thanks in advance!

My recommendation is to enable ADBon the the device and try to install it from a connected PC via adb install. This way you will get a detailed error message you can search here of SO to understand what is wrong with the APK.

@Robert The apk works perfectly fine when installed manually, the parsing error only occurs when installing it using the app. I couldn't find any error messages about it in logcat.

https://github.com/Yanndroid/NotiNotes/blob/0193b8b6caed1370d187d11020ae4f389bc9719e/app/src/main/java/de/dlyt/yanndroid/notinotes/QSTile.kt#L470
This is a working snippet that installs the apk.
